# альтернатива Си функциям с переменным количеством аргументов

Tags: c++, c, c++11, c++17

Есть в проекте функции void func(char* a, ...);
чем их можно заменить используя с++? И что скажете по быстродействию(медленнее альтернативное предложение или нет)

Answer (score 1):

Можно заменить тем же самым, т.к. они доступны в С++. А можно использовать variadic templates - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack. Альтернативное решение безопаснее и быстрее в рантайме, но может быть дороже для компиляции